# include line only if platform is Android

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

One problem that I have is that when I navigate to a page containing a form on android the keyboard pops up automatically. I found a solution for it but it only works on Android:

```
import { View } from "tns-core-modules/ui/core/view";

export class AutoFocusView extends View {

    createNativeView() {
        if (typeof android !== "undefined") {
            const linearLayout = new android.widget.LinearLayout(this._context);
            linearLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            linearLayout.setFocusable(true);
            return linearLayout;
        } 
        return super.createNativeView();
    }

    onLoaded() {
        super.onLoaded();
        this.requestFocus();
    }

    requestFocus() {
        const nativeViewProtected = this.nativeViewProtected;
        nativeViewProtected.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

I use this component. but it only works on android so I need to comment it from my code everytime I want to build for IOS. I was wondering if there was an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
import {isAndroid, isIOS} from '@nativescript/core';
```

then in your computed:

```
isandroid() {
                return isAndroid;
            }
```

then use this flag in any method you need:

```
if(isAndroid) {
  this.requestFocus();
}
```

You also can use this isAndroid flag in your template if need be with v-if.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `requestFocus()` only if platform is Android.

```
onLoaded() {
    super.onLoaded();
    if (typeof android !== "undefined") {
        this.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

You may also write it as a plugin within project, separate code for iOS and Android in platform specific file.

Comment: I personally used your solution but I accepted the other answer because I think it's more readable and I thought you are less in need of reputation ;) thank you:)